Issue with Multiple Spark Structured Streaming Jobs Consuming Same Kafka Topic
I have two separate Python scripts (job1.py and job2.py) that use Spark Structured Streaming to consume data from the Kafka topic test1. Both scripts are configured with the same Kafka consumer group (consumer-group-1), expecting that only one of them should consume the data at any time. However, when I run both scripts simultaneously and send data to test1 using bin/kafka-console-producer.sh, both jobs seem to process the same data.
job1.py:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length
import signal
import sys

checkpoint_dir = "/tmp/checkpoints"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaConsumer1") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.stateSchemaCheck", "true")
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

shutdown_requested = False

def shutdown_handler(signum, frame):
    global shutdown_requested
    print("Graceful shutdown initiated...")
    shutdown_requested = True
    query.stop()  

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown_handler)

df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", "test1") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .option("kafka.group.id", "consumer-group-1") \
    .load()

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")
df = df.withColumn("char_count", length(col("message")))

query = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", f"{checkpoint_dir}/wordcount_dta") \
    .start()

try:
    query.awaitTermination()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception encountered: {e}")


job2.py:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, length
import signal
import sys

checkpoint_dir = "/tmp/checkpoints"
kafka_bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("KafkaConsumer2") \
    .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.stateStore.stateSchemaCheck", "true")
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN")

shutdown_requested = False

def shutdown_handler(signum, frame):
    global shutdown_requested
    print("Graceful shutdown initiated...")
    shutdown_requested = True
    query.stop()  

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, shutdown_handler)

df = spark.readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
    .option("subscribe", "test1") \
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .option("kafka.group.id", "consumer-group-1") \
    .load()

df = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as message")
df = df.withColumn("char_count", length(col("message")))

query = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .format("console") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", f"{checkpoint_dir}/wordcount") \
    .start()

try:
    query.awaitTermination()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Exception encountered: {e}")


Steps to Reproduce:
Start both job1.py and job2.py simultaneously. Send messages to Kafka topic test1 using bin/kafka-console-producer.sh.
Expected Behavior: Only one Spark job (either job1.py or job2.py) should consume the messages from the Kafka topic due to using the same consumer group (consumer-group-1).
Actual Behavior: Both Spark jobs are processing the same messages concurrently, which is not the expected behavior with a shared consumer group.
Why are both Spark Structured Streaming jobs processing the same data from Kafka, even though they use the same consumer group? How can I ensure that only one job processes messages from the Kafka topic at any time, allowing seamless updates where I can start new jobs with updated queries and stop old ones without interruption or duplication?

Kafka consumer group distribute the events from topic by partitions to the consumers.In your job you can assign different partitions of the topic to each job.
Example if your kafka topic has 4 partition then assign 2 partitions to each job
Job1: // assigning 0,1 partitions to job1
 df = spark.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
.option("assign", "{'test1':[0,1]'}") \
.option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
.option("kafka.group.id", "consumer-group-1") \
.load()

Job2: // assigning 2,3 partitions to job2
df = spark.readStream \
.format("kafka") \
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafka_bootstrap_servers) \
.option("assign", "{'test1':[2,3]'}")
.option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
.option("kafka.group.id", "consumer-group-1") \
.load()

Check this out if you where able to distribute the events across the multiple job2
Note:
If you have only 1 partition you need increase the parallelism to create more partitions in your kafka, also to send the data to kafka use the key also which will distribute the data across the kafka partitions.

thanks for the response, it did solve the problem but is there any way like can we not specify the partitions rather they would get automatically assigned like it does in normal kafka method
like if i do not use the assign and explicitly set the partitions and use the   .option("subscribe", "test1") \ then both consumers are consuming the same data from the topic .

For your use case the kafka.group.id should work, to automatically distribute across the consumer in a group. Try to file a ticket to Apache Spark if you still requires.

Due to the nature of Spark Structured Streaming, both jobs may end up consuming from all partitions of the topic concurrently, especially if they start at the same time.
Do,

Start job1.py first and let it establish the Kafka consumer group and begin processing.
Start job2.py only after job1.py has successfully started and is actively processing data.

This sequential start-up helps Kafka distribute the partitions between the jobs correctly.

Thanks forthe response @roger yes i did the same have started the job1 and sent the data to it and it processed the same and the results were printing on the console in batches but when ido kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list it displays nothing here in this case there must be a consumer group named consumer-group-1 right but its empty  if i try the same with normal kafka python code where i set the consumer and produce the messages then it displays the consumer group using the above command not able to figure it out why for pyspark job it is not showing
